# Failed to plot graph of two arrays in Octave

Tags: arrays, plot, octave

I have created two arrays in octave using a for loop and I want to create a graph using the data of the two arrays. But it showed an error " invalid value for array property "xdata"" and displayed an empty graph.

```
for i=1:16
 x=1+(10^6)*2
 h{i}=1/(10.^i)
 fdd1{i}=(sin(1+h{i})-sin(1))/h{i}
 error_f1{i}=fdd1{i}-cos(1)
endfor
**fplot(loglog(h,error_f1));**
```

Am I making mistakes in plotting the graph? May I know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing all the possible mistakes in that snippet.

1. your variables `h` and `error_f` are cell arrays. The function `loglog` takes numeric arrays. I believe your specific error comes from there. You can convert them with `cell2mat` as in `loglog (cell2mat (h), cell2mat (error_f1))` but I would argue that would still be incorrect since you should have never created a cell array in the first place (see point 4).
2. your data has non-positive values which you can't plot with logarithmic scale.
3. the `fplot` function takes a function handle as argument. Why are you passing a figure handle (the output of `loglog`) to it?
4. Octave is a language designed around vectorized operations. It's syntax has a strong emphasis and you will suffer if you don't. You should not have a for loop for this. Just remove your indexing and make your multiplication and division element-wise. This also fixes problem 1 since you will end up with a numeric array

---

```
r = 1:16;
x = 1 + (10^6)*2;
h = 1 ./ (10.^r);
fdd1 = (sin (1+h) - sin (1)) ./ h;
error_f1 = fdd1 - cos(1);
```

Rule of thumb in Octave: if you ever see a for loop, chances are you are doing it wrong.